# Difference between assigning a boolean variable a value and assigning a result of a comparison in Java

Tags: java, boolean, variable-assignment

My collegues passed me some code, and there are problems when I run the code. Here is some part of it

```
boolean purchased = false;
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, connectionUser, connectionPassword);
stmt = conn.createStatement();
String sql = new StringBuilder().... // some query

rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
while (rs.next()) {
    //some code
    purchased = rs.getInt("purchased") == 1;
    print(" purchased:" + purchased);
}
```

This always printed purchased as false. I changed that part to this:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    //some code
    if(rs.getInt("purchased") == 1) purchased = true;
    print(" purchased:" + purchased);
}
```

Now it works perfectly.

*note:*  my ResultSet can have only 1 record. And in DB *purchased* is **bit** type, so there can be no other values than 0/1.

What is the difference between those two ways of writing ? as I know both should work the same way.

Comment: (1) if a value can be either `0` or `1` then it's effectively a boolean in Java. (2) If `rs` has only 1 record, wouldn't the `while` loop run once? Is the loop going to run more than once?

Answer (score 11):

> What is the difference between those two ways of writing ? as I know both should work the same way.

No, definitely not. In your first piece of code, if `rs.getInt("purchased")` returns a value *other than* 1, you assign a value of `false`.

In your second piece of code, once `purchased` has been set to `true`, it stays `true` for the rest of the loop.

So suppose your first row has a value of 1 for `purchased`, and your second row has a value of 2, then in your first piece of code the variable will become `true` then `false`, but in your second piece of code the variable will be set to `true` in the first iteration and then not changed in the second iteration.

Comment: I edited my question a bit, cause forgot to mention, that there can be only 1 record in ResultSet. Also in DB Purchased is 0 or 1, so no problem with having another value other than 1.

Comment: @Astgh: Well I suspect you're mistaken about there only being one record. Have you debugged through the code? Basically, I've explained what the difference is between these two pieces of code... the rest is up to you.

Answer (score 4):

Actually it's this code that's equivalent to your colleague's code:

```
while (rs.next()) {
    // some code
    if(rs.getInt("purchased") == 1) 
        purchased = true;
    else purchased = false;
    print(" purchased:" + purchased);
}
```

Now they'll behave the same since `purchased` is not set to `true` forever once it's set.

Comment: I agree, you are correct. But I missed to tell that there is only one record, so `else` doesn't make any change in this case, as I think and also as I checked adding/removing `else` =)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that once the variable becomes true you are never changing it to false. You need to determine which is correct, based on the contract of the method, or the expected behaviour.

It doesn't seem at all likely that your version is correct.

Answer (score 1):

How many records are in `ResultSet` and corresponding values?

It would not have made a difference without `while` loop ( if first record returns value as 1 ) or if ResultSet has only one record with value as 1.

`while` loop in first code might be setting `false` value in second iteration or so. So at the exit time of while loop, *purchased* value being carried is `false`.  In second way, you are setting *purchased*  value to true when value is 1 and that is not again getting reset to `false` ( because *purchased* value is not getting reset for other rows of ResultSet).

Hope it helps !!

Comment: There can be only 1 record in ResultSet. So there is no problem for second loop.

Comment: if there is only one record and `rs.getInt()` is returning 1 then both codes will print `true`.

Comment: That's what I am saying. I just missed that part in my main question. I will add it right now.

Comment: so even in that case, both codes behaving differently?

Comment: Yes. in Previous version it Always printed purchase as false, and after my changes it prints false when purchased is 0 in DB and true, when purchased is 1 in DB.

Comment: I think, you need to edit question to specify your DB and actual DB datatype too. paste a snapshot of DB table SELECT query result.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ***Jon Skeet*** that in your first answer the value changes on each iteration of the while loop, but in the second piece of code the value of the boolean variable does not change every time.

I don't know your requirement but I think you should also add the else part in code as well to change the boolean the value of `rs.getInt("purchased")` other than 1 , as in your existing code you only make the boolean variable true.